# dependend margin in div

Tags: jquery, css, html

This is the first time that I'm using this forum, normaly I allways find my answers here without asking them myself. So if I'm making any mistakes I apologize.
What I'm trying to do is the following:
I have a header that fits the window size (100%) through css. (the height changes through jquery but I don't think that's relevant for this question).
In this header I have an image which I want the middle of it in the middle of the screen.
Like this ( I'm not allowed to put images on this forum) :

```
 <----------------image------------------>
 __________ ____________________ __________
|          |                    |          |
|  REST    |                    |   REST   |
|        IM|AGE  IMAGE IMAGE  IM|AGE       |
|__________|____________________|__________|
           |                    |
           |____________________|
             <-----screen------>

REST = not visible (outside the screen)
```

So if the screen would be bigger it would show more of the image, but it would still be perfectly aligned in the middle.
So far everything i have done went well.

Made the following code:

```
 <div id="header">
    <div id="header_bg"><img src="pics/headerbg.jpg" id="stretch"></div>
    <div id="logo">
            <div class="logo"><img src="pics/logo.png" width="401" height="174"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the jquerycode:

```
if ( $("#stretch").width() > $(window).width()  ) {
            $screen = $(window).width();
            $pic = $("#stretch").width();
            $rest = $pic - $screen;
            $margin = $rest /2;
            $margin = $margin - $margin - $margin ;
            $('#stretch').css({'margin-left':($margin)+'px'});
        }
```

As you can see this works fine BUT, when I load the page for the very first time it hides too much of the image so that I get and empty space on the right side.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: better use `viewport` meta tag

Comment: This line looks a little crazy: `$margin = $margin - $margin - $margin ;`  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Also, don't use `$` prefix on variables unless its a jquery object

Comment: Hey Guys, thnx for the quick answer.
What do you mean with the viewport metatag Miqdad Ali?

Comment: The line:
$margin = $margin - $margin - $margin ;

Is indead a little bit crazy. I couldn't find a way to make the margin negative so i made it like this.
50 - 50 - 50 = -50 
If there is a quicker way i would be happy to use that one.

What i'm doing is-> i'm looking for the extra space of the image, then i take the half of that space and make that a negative margin-left in css

Comment: so for example:
the image is 1000px the screen is 500px
there is 500px that isn't shown, i make the image slide 250px out of the screen (to the left)
so i have 250px (rest), 500px image (shown inside of the screen), 250px (rest out of the screen on the right).

Comment: How about just `$margin = -$rest / 2;`

Comment: That works fine indeed. I changed that line but that wasn't the problem. It's really strange that it's only the first time that it's not working. Do you have any idea what might solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand you but if you only need have a picture centered in middle of screen, you can use Css property background with center position.

```
<style>
   #header_bg { background: url('pics/headerbg.jpg') no-repeat center 0; }
</style>

 <div id="header">
    <div id="header_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="logo">
            <div class="logo"><img src="pics/logo.png" width="401" height="174"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Especially as the image is named headerbg.jpg, it probably does make more sence to be a background image.

Comment: It is the background image of my header section. As far as i can see the css solution works great. What about older browsers?

Comment: Eh T-mo-T this is a standard solution, this will works in all browsers. You did'nt need javascript for solutions easy like this...

Comment: Ok thank you David. My final solution is based on what you showed me.
There was one thing that bothered me... If the picture's height didn't change. I needed to make the height stretch a little bit when the picture's height was smaller than the div's height.
I'll post my the solution below.
You were a great help, thanks a lot!
BTW i would like to know more about the code of css you wrote. You don't have an article about it?

Answer (score 0):

I came up to the following code that is based on the code David Slavik mentioned before. Thanks again for your solution David.

```
<style>
  #header_bg { 
    background: url('../pics/headerbg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover; /*opera*/
    background-size: cover; /*generic*/ }
</style>
```

This code makes sure that if the image is smaller then the height of the div it stretches a little bit.
Thanks everybody for your answers. For me this topic is closed.